# nginx logging to unix socket fails with protocol error

Tags: nginx, debian, logging, syslog, socket

debian stable,
nginx version: nginx/1.14.2

I get the following error message (error.log) : **connect() failed (91: Protocol wrong type for socket)**

configuration file :

```
access_log syslog:server=unix:/var/log/nginx/test.sock;
```

extra info:

- I listen to socket like so: socat - unix-listen:/var/log/nginx/test.sock
- I have made sure nginx has sufficient access rights to write (chmod 777 for testing)
- logging to UDP & TCP works fine
- selinux is disabled by default in debian stable

Comment: How did you configure your syslog server to listen on this socket?

Comment: `access_log` may be trying to open a datagram socket. I notice that `unix-listen` creates a "UNIX domain stream socket". You could try using one of the address types that create a "UNIX domain datagram socket".

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I didn't, like I wrote, using socat to listen to the socket.

Comment: @RichardSmith, thank you Richard, that was it. I switched to unix-recv and it worked like a charm. Please feel free to post an answer and I will accept it.